# How do you use functions in a different js file in phaser 3?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Im trying to create a js file with functions relevant to my game but i get an error message saying

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')

when i try to use phaser functions outside of the main file.

I have 2 files one called `game.js` and one called `test.js`. I am also using the matter physics engine.

**game.js :**

```
class bootScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    //Preloading assets for later use
    preload() {
        this.load.image('linus', 'assets/linus.png');
        this.load.script('t','test.js')
    }

    create() { }

    update() {
        //launch game scene
        this.scene.launch('game').stop();
    }
}

class playScene extends Phaser.Scene {

    constructor() {
        super('game');        
    }

    create() {
        test('test',1,1,'linus');
    }

    update() { }
}

// set the configuration of the game
let config = {
    type: Phaser.WEBGL, // Phaser will use WebGL if available, if not it will use Canvas
    width: 1280,
    height: 720,
    pixelArt: true,
    transparent: false,
    autoCenter: true,
    backgroundColor: '#000000',
    physics: {
        default: 'matter',
        matter: {
            restingThresh: 2,
            // debug: {
            //     renderFill: false
            // },
            gravity: {
                y: 0
            }
        }
    },
    scene: [bootScene, playScene]
};

// create a new game, pass the configuration
let game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

**test.js:**

```
function test(msg,x,y,texture){
    console.log(msg)
    this.matter.add.image(x,y,texture)
}
```

I have tried trying to put `t.test(etc.)` and adding the load script in preload. I tried looking up examples, but I couldn't find any.

Sorry if this is a really obvious fix or im just terrible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to pass the current `scene`, as a parameter, to the `test` function, and you will can access the `matter` object and other properties / functions, from the `scene`.

```
function test(scene, msg, x, y, texture) {
    console.log(msg);
    scene.matter.add.image(x, y, texture);
}
```

And the function `test` would have to be called, with the "current scene" in the case it is `this`:

```
 ...
 create() {
     ...
     test(this, 'test', 1, 1, 'linus');
     ...
 }
```

**This example of the offical website**: [Example Script Loading](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/loader/script/load-script), illustrates this fact indirect. Im that example the `scene` is not passed as paramter, but the `canvas` and the `context` are.
So following this example, passing the `scene` should solve your problem.

> **Side Note:** In general, if there is no specific reason, to load scripts from inside of a phaser application *(as shown above)*, I would load the scripts within the html-file or use a web-bundler like *webpack* or others. *Not only for performance/minification reason.*